# How can I update node.js and install grunt/bower in a python project in Travis CI?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, bower, travis-ci

I need to use grunt during the installation of my project. I need node.js >= 0.8 for that. but the version included in a python VM in Travis CI is the 0.6.

I tried downloading the last binaries and inserting it into the PATH but I couldn't export the variable correctly, and if I changed it using the env: parameter of travis it would not have had the rest of the PATH.

If I use directly the binaries (`./node-v0.10.22-linux-x64/bin/npm install ...`), it will install them in `./node-v0.10.22-linux-x64/bin/` and when I want to use grunt, it will call bower (one of the task) but it will fail. (Fatal error: Failed to execute git checkout e6f8a58dbce5858586564a1ba4543f122ef63225, exit code of #128).

So, what is the best solution to update node.js and install binaries I need to use them in Travis CI?

Comment: Are you sure about the Node version on Travis? The build environment was updated yesterday, but I don't remember it using 0.6 in over a year.

Comment: Here is a part of the error shown by npm when it failed:

npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4

Comment: I believe you can use NVM to switch versions properly, but don't quote me on that. PS 0.10.22 should have been shipped on the 20th

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the Travis config that I have been using. The steps to get node installed are adapted from [node's install docs](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os). This method will install the latest stable version of node.

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
  - "3.3"

install:
  # Python test requirements
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install nose coverage selenium

  # JavaScript test requirements
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
  - sudo apt-get -y update
  - sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
  - sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
  - sudo npm install -g bower
  - sudo npm install

before_script:
  - bower install

script:
  # Run Python tests and generate coverage statistics
  - nosetests --with-coverage

  # Run tests for JavaScript
  - grunt test

# etc., etc.
```

Comment: @mjumbewu This isn't working for me, there's v0.10.36 before and after: https://github.com/hugovk/test/blob/upgrade-node/.travis.yml https://travis-ci.org/hugovk/test/jobs/166663128

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI's [Trusty beta](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment) comes with "A mega image which will contains almost all of (soon to be all) our commonly supported runtimes and services."

To use it, add this to your .travis.yml:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
```

For example:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty

language: python

python:
- 'pypy'
- 'pypy3'
- '2.6'
- '2.7'
- '3.2'
- '3.3'
- '3.4'
- '3.5'

script:
  - python --version
  - node --version
```

At the time of writing, this contains Node v4.1.2 instead of v0.10.36.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working travis file now, but I am not really happy with this solutions:

```
language: python
python: 2.7
install:
  - sudo apt-get -qq install libfreetype6-dev liblcms1-dev libwebp-dev memcached
  - wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.22/node-v0.10.22-linux-x64.tar.gz
  - tar xzvf node-v0.10.22-linux-x64.tar.gz
  - sudo ./node-v0.10.22-linux-x64/bin/npm install -g bower grunt-cli
  - mkdir -p buildout-cache/eggs
  - mkdir -p buildout-cache/downloads
  - python bootstrap.py -c travis.cfg
  - bin/buildout -N -c travis.cfg install download install
  - bin/buildout -N -c travis.cfg
  - cd path/to/resources/folder
  - sudo ../../../../node-v0.10.22-linux-x64/bin/npm install
  - ../../../../node-v0.10.22-linux-x64/bin/bower install
  - ../../../../node-v0.10.22-linux-x64/bin/grunt
  - cd -
```

I corrected the error in bower by changing the target to master (from a specific commit id). I don't know why it doesn't work on travis but works locally.